# Destroy window.onresize event subscriber

Tags: javascript, dom

If I subscribe to window.onresize (in a single page app), do I need to unsubscribe to avoid a memory leak? If so, how do I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var heightOutput = document.querySelector('#height');
  var widthOutput = document.querySelector('#width');

  function resize() { 
    heightOutput.textContent = window.innerHeight;
    widthOutput.textContent = window.innerWidth;
  }

  window.onresize = resize;
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unsubscribe, you can use:

```
// Subscribe
window.onresize = resize;

// Unsubscribe
window.onresize = null;
```

This method will only allow you to provide *one* function to be executed on `resize`.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
// Subscribe
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

// Unsubscribe
window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
```

Using this approach, you can attach multiple event listeners to the same event. You *do* have to keep a reference to the method you've attached in order to be able to remove it, however.

Not disposing a subscription to an event won't necessarily create memory leaks. When you, for example, create a `<button>` with a `click` event subscription, the subscription will be removed once the `<button>` is removed from the DOM and has no references in code. (at least, in modern browsers)

Still, it's always nice to put some extra thought into the way you're handling subscriptions and remove unneeded listeners.

Comment: Wether it works, depends on the way you've attached any subscribers. If you've used `addEventListener` or jQuery's `.resize`, `onresize = null` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to memory leaks:

While there used to be some heavy concerns with memory leaks and the DOM, to the best of my knowledge, no modern browser has trouble with that anymore.

(This used to be mostly an IE issue.)

I found a discussion of the DOM memory leaks if you're interested in understanding what caused them -- but again, in today's work I wouldn't worry too much.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks

With the resize event, I expect you're only going to be attaching it it once -- and there is only one `window` object, so I wouldn't give it a second thought.

Comment: If you have a multi-components app in the browser, you might be binding to window resize from literally hundreds of widgets. As we currently do something like this, you're last sentence has no comfort value whatsoever ;-) "I expect you'll only attach it once"
The memory leaks link is dead